# React validation: validating same form in two different components

Tags: validation, reactjs, material-ui

I am using react with material-ui.

I have three components:

1. FieldsComponent - holds form fields.
2. CreateComponent - has FieldsComponent and a submit button
3. UpdateComponent - has FieldsComponent and an update button

How do i validate FieldsComponent when the submit/update buttons are clicked on the Create/Update Components?

Is there a better approach?

Edit: some code...

The Fields:

```
class PlaceFields extends Component {

    render() {

        return(
            <div className="PlaceFields">
                <TextField
                    ref="placeName"
                    floatingLabelText="Place name"
                />
                <br/>
                <TextField
                    ref="placeAddress"
                    floatingLabelText="Place address"
                />
                <br/>
                <TextField
                    floatingLabelText="More details"
                    multiLine={true}
                    rows={2}
                    rowsMax={4}
                    style={{textAlign: 'left'}}/>
                <FlatButton
                    label="Choose an Image"
                    labelPosition="before"
                    className="uploadButton"
                    containerElement="label"
                >
                    <input type="file" className="uploadInput" />
                </FlatButton>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

First use of the Fields (the second use is within PlacesCard which is shown below..

```
class App extends Component {

...

return (

            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="cardsContainer">
                        <PlacesCard/>
                    </div>
                    <FloatingActionButton
                        className="AddPlaceFAB"
                        onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}
                    >
                        <ContentAdd />
                    </FloatingActionButton>
                    <Dialog
                        title="Create a place"
                        actions={actions}
                        modal={true}
                        open={this.state.open}
                    >
                        <PlaceFields/>
                        <RaisedButton label="Create" primary={true}/>
                    </Dialog>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
}
```

Second use inside PlacesCard:

```
const PlacesCard = () => (
    <Card className="card">
        <CardHeader
            className="cardHeader"
            title="Place name"
            subtitle="address"
            actAsExpander={true}
            showExpandableButton={true}
        />

        <div expandable={true}>
            <PlaceFields/>
            <CardActions>
                <RaisedButton label="Save" primary={true}/>
            </CardActions>
        </div>
    </Card>
);
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Where are you holding the state of the fields?

Comment: @TylerSebastian Added code.

Comment: @StephenL Right now nowhere. It's just the template. Where should i?